# How are hexadecimal numbers created in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time understanding

```js
console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16));
```

how this actually creates a number, for example 2b3F23. I read about `Math.floor()` and `Math.random()`, but cannot understand the process of creating the 6 digit number. I read about the different numerical systems, but only understood the "0-9" and "A-F" or "a-f" in the hexadecimal system.

I also looked up in Wikipedia and I am unable to understand this statement:

> Hexadecimal is used in the transfer encoding `Base16`, in which each byte of the plaintext is broken into two 4-bit values and represented by two hexadecimal digits.

If someone could explain really well how exactly does the JS create this 6 digit number I would really appreciate it.
P.S I apologise if the question is silly or inconvenient.

Comment: The `.toString()` function accepts a parameter, which is interpreted as the numeric base for the string representation. Numbers are not "hexadecimal" in any case; that's a string representation, just like a decimal string is a representation. The actual number is a binary floating-point value.

Comment: Are you asking how to convert a number from its decimal representation into its hexadecimal representation or how `.toString(16)` works?

Comment: @Andreas My question is the related to random number, which we get above, how is it converted to a hexadecimal number? I mean if i get a number lets say 12,234 how is that converted to a hexadecimal number ?

Comment: did you read about [Number.prototype.toString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers are just numbers. When we write them down, we use numbering systems that have a "base" (aka "radix"), which determines when you go from a single "place" (for instance, 9) to two places (for instance, 10) and so on (100, 1000, ...). In decimal, the one you're probably most familiar with, the base is 10 — that is, you count 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and then you go to two digits: 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22 and so on.

In hexadecimal, the base is 16. So you count 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, and then go to two digits: 10 (which is 16 in decimal).

So in your code:

- `Math.random() * 16777215` comes up with a number somewhere between 0 (inclusive) and 16777215 (exclusive), for instance 2834211.153154
- `Math.round` rounds any fractional portion of that toward 0, for instance to 2834211.
- `toString(16)` creates a string for that number in hexadecimal (the 16 passed to `toString` tells it what number base to use). 2834211 decimal is 2B3F23 hexadecimal.